# row.name using `structure` function as c(NA, *integer*)

Tags: r, dataframe

Does anyone know why when I run this:

```
row.names(structure(list(speed = c(4, 7), dist = c(2, 22)), 
                    row.names = c(NA, 2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I get this:

```
# "1" "2"
```

and not `c(NA, 2L)`? I mean what `row.names` argument in `structure` exactly does to the argument?

I came across this when I tried to use `dput` to see the structure of some dataframes. e.g.

```
dput(cars)
```

And I noticed the `row.names` argument in it, which is: `c(NA, 
-50L)`.

Comment: This is more to save space and how they are internally represented, `row.names` are characters which take up lot of space. There is a detailed discussion [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Help-with-quot-row-names-as-integer-c-NA-5-quot-in-file-from-dput-td914958.html).

Answer (score 1):

`c(NA, n)` is how data frames internally store the row names in the common case of 1:n so as to save space and processing time.  This is not supposed to be accessible to the user who is to regard it as "1", "2", ...  so the accessor functions translate it.